# Android: Can I directly link to the ratings tab of an app's page on Google Play

Tags: android, hyperlink, google-play

Can I directly link to the ratings tab of an app's page on Google Play?

If yes, what is the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only link to an app, a publisher, a collection, or search result. All of the others are not possible to link directly to.

You can find out how to link to these, and what *isn't* possible, in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html).

Comment: Linking to Collection seems not working ?? i've tried it and it gives ActivityNotFoundException  , any ideas ??

Answer (score 1):

You can't link to the ratings tab (if any) on Google Play. The only thing you can do is link to the app's page and add an on-screen toast with a 1 sentence instruction on how to rate the app (e.g. "Scroll down and click 'Review' ... ")